# Is there an easy way to lock/unlock editing in an Excel or Word file shared over OneDrive?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-word, onedrive, shared-access

OneDrive gives you the option to share Word, Excel, etc. files with others and allow or restrict editing, but is there an easy way to toggle the editing permission on and off without cancelling and re-sending the share link?

I have an Excel sheet that I want a bunch of people to be able to edit at the same time throughout the week, but I'd like to be able to limit editing permissions to myself only when I share the file in weekly meetings.

Answer (score 0):

### Word

### In the document itself, you can use Restrict Editing - No Changes.

*You can turn this on and off with a password.*
You will find this on both the Reviewing and the Developer Tabs.

You can except certain parts of the document from this restriction.
*If on **SharePoint**, you can also give permission to limited other people.*

### Excel

Likewise, in Excel, you can Protect the workbook with a password, which you can remove. There are other options as well.